# Magento 2.1 How to get custom configuration in custom observer?

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, configuration

I am using Magento 2.1 and I am trying to get my custom configuration field's values in my custom observer.

I have tried implementing [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159097/magento-2-get-admin-config-values) solution, but it is not working.

I am trying using object manager in my observer:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $qty1 = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('membership/general/qty1');
```

System.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="beadsventure" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>beadsventure</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="membership" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Membership Discount</label>
            <tab>beadsventure</tab>
            <resource>BeadsVenture_Membership::membership_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="qty1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Quantity for Level 1</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Quantity for Level 1 (If empty then Default value is 3).</comment>
                </field>
                 <field id="price1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price for Level 1</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Price for Level 1 (If empty then Default value is $500).</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="qty2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Quantity for Level 2</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Quantity for Level 2 (If empty then Default value is 5).</comment>
                </field>
                 <field id="price2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price for Level 2</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Price for Level 2 (If empty then Default value is $1500).</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="qty3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Quantity for Level 3</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Quantity for Level 3 (If empty then Default value is 10).</comment>
                </field>
                 <field id="price3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price for Level 3</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Price for Level 3 (If empty then Default value is $3000).</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="qty4" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Quantity for Level 4</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Quantity for Level 4 (If empty then Default value is 20).</comment>
                </field>
                 <field id="price4" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price for Level 4</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                    <comment>This will threshold Price for Level 4 (If empty then Default value is $5000).</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Observer:

```
namespace BeadsVenture\Membership\Observer;



    class Beadsmemberamount implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {     
        public function decide_group_id ($amount, $id, $qty)
        {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $price1 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('membership/general/price1');
            if($amount >= $price1) {
                $id = 4;
            }
            return $id;
        }
    }
```

Please Help!

Comment: What problem your have facing

Comment: Please share the system.xml code and also it  observer code

Comment: @AmitBera Updated the details

Comment: code seems code. Are sure that you observer is running?

Comment: Yes it is running, I haven't mentioned my "execute" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add function in observer file:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
```

and update your code:

```
 public function decide_group_id ($amount, $id, $qty)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $price1 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('membership/general/price1');
        if($amount >= $price1) {
            $id = 4;
        }
        return $id;
    }
```

with

```
 public function decide_group_id ($amount, $id, $qty)
    {
        $price1 = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('membership/general/price1', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if($amount >= $price1) {
            $id = 4;
        }
        return $id;
     }
```

After that clear cache and run command
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile.